# error invalid windows mount type: 'bind' on Windows 10 docker build of Windows container

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, windows-server-container

I just installed the latest Windows 10 Pro 20H2. After installing Docker Desktop and switching it for Windows containers, it asked me to do the following

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("Microsoft-Hyper-V", "Containers") -All
```

After this was done, my PC restarted and all seem good. Then I saved the `Dockerfile` below in an empty directory under my Documents. I build this Dockerfile with success in a CI system before, but I want to build in my machine for quicker development cycle.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

RUN powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command \
    netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces ; \
    netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface 18 mtu=1460 store=persistent ; \
    netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces ; \
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')) ; \
    choco install -y --no-progress git --params "/GitAndUnixToolsOnPath" ; \
    choco install -y --no-progress 7zip ; \
    Remove-Item C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs -Force -Recurse ;
```

I want to build this Dockerfile, so on the directory that contains it, in Powershell I typed:

```
docker build .
```

But I got the error:

```
[+] Building 0.0s (2/2) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 646B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: failed to mount C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\buildkit-mount316756066: [{Type:bind Source:C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\exjneuxdwo67rh9g5rfomdpc2 Options:[rbind ro]}]: invalid windows mount type: 'bind'
```

What is this error `invalid windows mount type: 'bind'` ?

```
docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d`
```

I also followed the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/building-sample-app but still got the same `invalid windows mount type: 'bind'` error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

In docker settings, make sure to have `buildkit` set to **`false`** as below:

```
  "features": {
    "buildkit": false
  }
```

After this is applied and successfully restarted, the build should proceed.

In the docs, it's currently mentioned BuildKit is a feature "only supported for building Linux containers" : https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/

Unfortunately in a fresh install it's value defaults to true and doesn't change to false when switching to Windows Containers.

Comment: I pinged Docker on this and the feedback I'm hearing is that buildkit is not enabled by default when you switch to Windows containers. If you're seeing otherwise, open up an issue with the steps to reproduce at https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues

Comment: Still got this issue today on a fresh Windows 10 and new installation. And Docker wants to charge for Docker Desktop...

Answer (score 0):

This is also impacted by the environment variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT`, which can override the setting in the config file.

A value of `1` enables it, a value of `0` disables it.

Answer (score 0):

If flipping buildkit to false doesn't work for you:

You should also be sure that your Visual Studio is running as Administrator.  The Docker files for binding are not accessible otherwise.